# How to make a call to .aspx https from php script from my localhost with xamp?

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, sms-gateway

I am trying to send SMS from my localhost with xamp installed.
Requested page is on https and an .aspx page. 
I am getting error: "HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed." or blank page only in some cases.
Detaisl is as follows :

```
$url = 'https://www.ismartsms.net/iBulkSMS/HttpWS/SMSDynamicAPI.aspx';
$postArgs = 'UserId='.$username.
    '&Password='.$password.
    '&MobileNo='.$destination.
    '&Message='.$text.
    '&PushDateTime='.$PushDateTime.
    '&Lang='.$Lang;
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
$response = getSslPage($all);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response); exit;
```

I tried every possible solution/combination found on internet but could not resolve that. The API developers do not have a example for php script.
I tried httpful php library and file_get_contents function but getting empty page. Also tried every combination with curl_setup.

I need to call this url without any post data and see the response from it.
Instead getting a blank page.

Please note that when I execute the url with all details in browser it works fine.

Can anybody help me in this regard.

Thank you,
Usman

Comment: $all = $url."?".$postArgs;    $response = getSslPage($all);

Answer (score 1):

First do `urlencode` over your data as follows:

```
$postArgs = 'UserId='. urlencode($username.
'&Password='.urlencode($password).
'&MobileNo='.urlencode($destination).
'&Message='.urlencode($text).
'&PushDateTime='.urlencode($PushDateTime).
'&Lang='.urlencode($Lang);
```

After that two possible solutions. One is using `GET`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "?" . $postArgs);
```

Second option is using `POST` method.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
```

Comment: Thank you @Sabuj for replying. I tried some combinations and it worked. Adding the code if somebody ever worked this API.

Comment: `code` $url = 'https://www.ismartsms.net/iBulkSMS/HttpWS/SMSDynamicAPI.aspx';
    $data = http_build_query(array('UserId' => $username, 'Password' => $password,'MobileNo' => $destination, 'Message' => $text,'PushDateTime' => $PushDateTime, 'Lang' => $Lang));
    $requestData = $url."?".$data;`code`